# Printing out associated key with values in Perl in foreach loop

Tags: perl

I am trying to print out the key for the hash if the value satisfies a certain condition. However, I am not sure how to access the hash key if it satisfies the value condition. This is the code I have:

```
foreach my $x (values %hash){
    if ($x > $ARGV[1]){
        $counter = $counter + 1
        print "keys %hash\n"
    }
}
print "$counter\n"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you loop over the values, you have no access to the key.

```
for my $key (keys %hash) {
    if ($hash{$key} > $ARGV[1]) {
        $counter = $counter + 1;
        print "$key\n";
    }
}
print "$counter\n";
```

or

```
keys %hash; # reset iterator
while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
    if ($value > $ARGV[1]) {
        $counter = $counter + 1;
        print "$key\n";
    }
}
print "$counter\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the key of a hash element given its value. After all, multiple keys may have the same value. But you *can* rely on Perl giving you the keys in the same order as the values. So you could write something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @keys = keys %hash;
my @vals = values %hash;
my $count = 0;

for my $val ( @values ) {
    my $key = shift @keys;
    if ( $val > $ARGV[1] ) {
        ++$count;
        print $key, "\n";
    }
}

print "$count\n";
```

But it would be far better to use a `while` loop with `each` to gather both the key and the value at the same time

```
while ( my ($key, $val) = each %hash ) {
    if ( $val > $ARGV[1] ) {
        ++$count;
        print $key, "\n";
    }
}
```